resize2fs shrinking ext4 safely
The thing I need to do is to shrink ext4 filesystem, and then recreate partition. Overall I know what needs to be done, the process is pretty straightforward. But there is one little thing that makes me paranoid.
If you read the man page, it starts with the words:

The resize2fs program will resize ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems.
It can be used to enlarge or shrink an unmounted file system located
on device.

So, okay, it seems that it cat shrink ext4 fs. But:

If you wish to shrink an ext2 partition, first use resize2fs to shrink
the size of filesystem. Then you may use fdisk(8) to shrink the size
of the partition. When shrinking the size of the partition, make sure
you do not make it smaller than the new size of the ext2 filesystem!

No mention of ext4 file system at all.
Making a backup of the whole partition/fs is not an option, or at least, a major inconvenience in my case.
So, the question is - has anyone tried this? Can this program shrink an ext4 filesystem?

Yes, the same tool, the same process. Don't worry, ext4 is fully supported. Note you must disuse the filesystem before shrink, e.g. you umount it first. It is not possible to shrink mounted ext2/3/4 file system, but it's possible to extend it online. For this reason, the good space management habit is to not rely on the possibility of shrinking. You need to evaluate how much you really need and only allocate that much plus some safety margin, and extend it when you need more space. To catch up the right moment to extend you need to have some monitoring that would alert you.

@NikitaKipriyanov thanks a lot

They all are essentially the same filesystem, with incrementally more feature bits enabled.
Tools like resize2fs (as well as the kernel driver itself) look at the "incompatible features" field of the superblock to determine whether the tool supports all of the features that are active on that particular filesystem; if there is any new feature in ext2/3/4 that changes the layout (and therefore the resizing procedure) it would have a new feature bit so that incompatible kernels will refuse to mount it and incompatible tools will refuse to resize it.
